# Google Script cache XML bigger than 100kb alternative?

Tags: xml, caching, google-apps-script

i am just writing a library for extracting XML Data from an API Import.
To minimize calls i used the cache like :

```js
function getAssetData_() {
   var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
   var cached = cache.get("asset_xml");
   if (cached != null) {
     return cached;
   }
   var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(EveBuildUrl_("AssetList")); 
   cache.put("asset_xml", result, 3600); // cache for 60 minutes
   return result;
```

Now i have the problem that one XML file is too big for the cache (limit 100kb).
Is there another possibillity to "cache" this file?

Answer (score 1):

http://qiang-li.blogspot.hu/2012/05/cache-101-with-google-apps-script.html
https://github.com/yinonavraham/GoogleAppsScripts/tree/master/EnhancedCacheService

Chunk the data and store the auto assigned keys as the value for the given key. The link is for a blog with a script.